# Notation with regards to percentage and order of magnitude - little dot next to percentage sign.

Tags: notation, percentages

Is anyone able to tell me if there is some notation that means 'an order of magnitude' or '/10' on a percentage value? I have a graph (see below) from a journal and the y-axis values are more than I would expect - I would expect in this instance 0 to 0.3% rather than 0 - 3% than seems to be shown on graph.

The quality of journal doc is pretty poor but there appears to be a little dot to the right of the percentage. I was wondering/ hoping this has some significance.

If anyone can shine a light it would be much appreciated.

[image]

zoomed up a bit...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a *[per mille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mille)* (${}^{\circ}/_{\circ \circ}$) symbol, which indicates a ratio in parts per $1000$, just as a percentage symbol indicates a ratio in parts per $100$.

Comment: @Travis The OP said "I would expect in this instance 0 to 0.3% rather than 0 - 3% than seems to be shown on graph." -- I think a 'per mille' symbol perfectly answered the question and also that 'dot' next to the percentage sign inside the square bracket. Please, tell me why you think it's not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, Hao, I misunderstood the question when I reviewed your answer, and I agree your answer is very likely correct. (+1) (For what it's worth, I wasn't the person who downvoted you.)

Comment: I might include a little about what a 'per mille' symbol means in your answer; I know OP's question is asking for identification of a symbol and you do exactly this, but as your answer stands, quite possibly someone might flag it as a "link-only" answer, which is grounds for removal.

Comment: Sure, please do. Our discussion here may helps clarifying the answer a bit too. On the other hand, this question seems to be too specific to be helpful for others. And @Jon should be able to tell immediately whether it's the answer s/he wanted no matter what :)